# Not seeing unread messages in Gmail conversation when multiple new responses

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, gmail-conversations

I admit, there is some user error here, but this has happened to me enough times that it seems others may have experienced it and found solutions or workarounds.

This issue is with a Gmail conversation where there are a few new responses that are still unread.  In the Inbox, it may list several people's names, then the number of messages in the thread in parentheses, like "Eric, Steve, Jan (7)". But the problem is I don't know how many of those 7 messages are new/unread. I often open the conversation expecting that there is one new message.  When I open the conversation, I see the first new response expanded.  If the first unread message is just the right length, the end of the message ends right at or just off of the bottom of the window, so I don't see a header for a second message and it isn't obvious that there are more new/unread messages in the conversation.  I think I've read the only new message, so I click "Archive", and now there are several messages that were marked read because I opened the conversation, but I never actually saw them because I never scrolled the conversation down far enough.  So I'm not seeing messages where people are asking me to do things, then they think I'm ignoring them.

What would be nice is if Gmail could detect that the message hasn't been scrolled into view yet and either

1. Don't ever mark a message read until it scrolls into view, or
2. Warn me if I'm Archiving a conversation with unread messages that I never scrolled into view

I checked Settings, including Labs, to see if some setting like this existed, but I didn't see one.  Does anyone know of a plugin or setting or workaround of some sort that would keep me from making this mistake again?

Comment: I tend to click the header of the last open message I see to see if there are other messages following.

Comment: I experience this issue too. I've missed some really important emails only to find them later in my archive. I think it might also happen when you see 1 reply in your inbox, but your inbox hasn't synced for a few seconds, so you click the thread, read the first email, and archive. But somewhere in the interim, between your inbox having last synced, and you pressing archive, the new message has arrived. Very frustrating!